# What is an estimated paint to primer ratio on exterior bare wood?

Tags: painting, paint, exterior, primer

I've used 3 gallons of KILZ Premium Primer (2 coats plus touch ups) and will top it with Behr's Premium Plus, Paint & Primer All in One, Exterior Satin Enamel in a Medium Base. Please don't tell me that many coats of primer is not necessary and that the Paint & Primer combo is overkill, because my goal is not to finish the job asap, but to get GREAT coverage that will last as long as possible.  It's worked very well for me in the past, just can't remember the approx. ratio. Thanks.

Comment: You want the best, you're on the right track.  Having used both the "better" Premium Plus and the "best" Marquee this year, its worth the extra few dollars to get the "best" Marquee paint.  1:1 (2 coats + 2 coats). It covers great

Comment: That sounds about right, freshop, thanks!  I'm looking forward to the paint goin' on like butter!

Answer (score 1):

300-400 sq feet per gallon coverage with kilz primer

250-400 sq feet per gallon coverage with your behr exterior paint.

With such a good primer base I would expect 325-350 sq feet per gallon on each of your 2 finish coats.

Answer (score 0):

Most paint manufacturers recommend 1 primer coat plus 2 finish coats.

I’m not sure about your question, but is that 1:2 ratio?

I’ve used the all in one paint and primer and had good luck with just 2 coats on new wood. However, it was extremely dry wood (moisture content < 5%) and was NOT cedar.

Comment: I don't see on the can where it says what the primer/paint ratio is.  I just want to seal the wood (Douglas Fir) really well, because it has been bare for about 4 years.  I'm not how much All In One paint/primer I should expect to use.  There is no wood showing thru with 2-1/2 coats of primer only and it looks like it's been painted.  I am guessing it will need 2 coats of All in One paint/primer, so to better state my question:  If it took 3 gallons of KILZ primer to cover the wood really well, will it take more, less, or about the same of the All in One paint/primer combo for good coverage?

Comment: @Jeani Based on a paint’s viscosity, it is generally assumed that a minimum thickness of one coat of paint is about 8mm. If it’s applied thinner, it may take more coats than recommend by the manufacturer. That is to say, you control the thickness the paint is applied so you control the number of coats. Another major factor is the surface “roughness”. The rougher the surface the more paint is required. Each manufacturer has a recommendation for area it will cover (based on viscosity and 8mm coverage).

Comment: I think you mean that a coat of paint is .8mm, not 8mm.

Comment: @Matthew I’m an American. How am I suppose to know metric?

Comment: 8mm is some damn good paint.   I agree with Lee's answer but to get a little scientific and pedantic the primer coat will be thicker than each of the layers.